# How to find the generating function of a certain OEIS sequece

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I encountered a counting problem very similar to this one https://oeis.org/A254233. Letting $a_n$ be the   number of ways to partition the multiset consisting of $n$ copies each of 1, 2, and 3 into $n$ sets of size 3, the OEIS entry is for the sequence $a_n$. According to the OEIS entry, the generating function for $a_n$  is
$$
x^{12}-x^{11}+x^{10}+3*x^9+5*x^8+x^7+4*x^6+x^5+5*x^4+3*x^3+x^2-x+1 
\over 
(x^2+1)\cdot (x^2-x+1)\cdot (x^2+x+1)^3\cdot (x+1)^4\cdot (x-1)^8
$$
However, no proof is given. Can anyone help explain how that generating function for $a_n$ is derived? I am hoping to use your explanation to learn about the general theory of generating functions, so I can apply that to solve my related problem.

Comment: You need to give details regarding your specific problem and your attempts to solve it. Without this information, your question is extremely broad, and possibly unanswerable. Please edit your post to show an attempt.

Comment: I don't want help with my problem, but to understand how the GF of this sequence https://oeis.org/A254233 can be found

Comment: But what is the context of your question, i.e. which counting problem?

Comment: I need to count the ways of subdividing 3N balls, such that N are green, N are blue and N are red, into k_1 baskets of 3 balls, k_2 baskets of 6 balls k_i baskets of 3i balls, for a given set of k_i

Comment: Or better yet, I am a physicist trying to understand how a strange matter plasma, consisting of an equal number of quarks up, down and strange can be partitioned into smallers chunks of matter conserving the initial number and composition of quarks

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to find the GF for https://oeis.org/A254233 (which may or may not be suited to your related situation):

There are ten types of sets that can appear, viz. {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, ..., {1, 2, 3}, ..., {3, 3, 3}.  A partition of the desired form is equivalent to a solution of the following system of equations in nonnegative integers:
$$\begin{cases} 3a_{111} + 2a_{112} + 2a_{113} + a_{122} + a_{123} + a_{133} = n \\ 3a_{222} + 2a_{122} + 2a_{223} + a_{112} + a_{123} + a_{233} = n \\
3a_{333} + 2a_{133} + 2a_{233} + a_{113} + a_{123} + a_{223} = n\end{cases}$$ (hopefully the variable names are self-explanatory).  Equivalently, you are seeking to count lattice points in the $n$-dilation of a $7$-dimensional polytope in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ defined by three (explicit) hyperplanes and the inequalities $a_{ijk} \geq 0$.  Since all coefficients are integers, this is a rational polytope, and we can apply Erhart theory: the number of points is going to be given by a quasi-polynomial function, of degree $7$ and with period bounded in terms of the denominators of the vertices.  With this knowledge, there is some finite number of terms you can compute and interpolate to find the general answer.  (This also explains why the function can be known a priori to satisfy a linear recurrence relation.)

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica has a `FindGeneratingFunction[]` function for
this kind of problem. If the sequence is known to satisfy a
[linear recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation)
(as A254233 does) then a little bit of
linear algebra is sufficient to find the numerator and
denominator polynomials of the rational generating function.